# Using the jQuery each() function to loop through classname elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to use jQuery to loop through a list of elements that have the same classname & extract their values.

I have this..

```
function calculate() {

    // Fix jQuery conflicts
    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){    

        // Get all items with the calculate className
        var items = jQuery('.calculate');



    });    

}
```

I was reading up on the each() function though got confused how to use it properly in this instance.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
jQuery('.calculate').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);

    var value = currentElement.val(); // if it is an input/select/textarea field
    // TODO: do something with the value
});
```

and if you wanted to get its index in the collection:

```
jQuery('.calculate').each(function(index, currentElement) {
    ...
});
```

Reference: [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) functions.

Comment: Thanks very much!! This may be a stupid question, but what does "it's index mean"?

Comment: It's the index in the collection. So for example if you have 3 elements that match the selector this variable will increment on each iteration et and it will represent the index of the current element.

Comment: One correction, with Rails and jquery-rails (3.1.0) the parameters are first index and then currentElemnt: `jQuery('.calculate').each(function(index,currentElement) ..`

Comment: Something I can use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277272/how-to-emulate-xslt-using-jquery-from-html-source ?

Answer (score 3):

```
        $('.calculate').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).text()
        });
```

Comment: This answer is not aligned with question: `$('.editable')` is neither declared in the question, nor in the answer