# How to use ClassName add entries to a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML source:

```
<span class="specLink">
    <specialty><a title="Plastic Surgery" href="link2.aspx">Plastic Surgery</a></specialty>
</span>
<br />
<span class="specLink">
    <specialty2><a title="Hand Surgery" href="link3.aspx">Hand Surgery</a></specialty2>
</span>
```

How can I create a JQuery script which runs during page load to displays the same list taking from the HTML Source listed above?

E.g.:

```
<div class="justPad">
    <a title="Plastic Surgery" href="link2.aspx" class="defaultLinks">Plastic Surgery</a>
</div>
<div class="justPad">
    <a title="Hand Surgery" href="link3.aspx" class="defaultLinks">Hand Surgery</a>
</div>
```

How I would like it to be:

```
var k = "";
$(".specLink").each(function() {
    var aLink = $(".specLink").replace(<%-- Remove the <specialty#></specialty#> tags and only keep the anchor link --%>);

    k += '<div class="justPad">'; //.. as many entries that shows up
    k += aLink; //.. as many entries that shows up
    k += '</div>'; //.. as many entries that shows up
});

//Once I have added 
$(".addSpecialties").html(k);
```

Blank HTML:

```
<div class="serviceHolder brClear addSpecialties">
    //add inside here from the JQuery above
</div>
```

Comment: Can you just show your HTML input and desired HTML output?

Comment: Sounds like you need AngularJS. Here is a free course http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro

Comment: @JorgeZuverza *"Sounds like you need AngularJS"* - I beg your pardon?!

Comment: Why would I use `AngularJS` when I am already using JQuery?

Comment: AngularJS and jQuery solve very different problems. The real question is *"Why would that problem indicate that I need AngularJS?"*, and I'm sure JorgeZuverza would have a pretty hard time explaining that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
var specialties = $(".specLink a").map(function() {
    return $('<div class="justPad">').append( $(this).clone() )[0];
}).toArray();

$(".addSpecialties").empty().append(specialties);
```

Comment: Do I have to add the closing `</div>`?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge nope, `<div...` here is not an opening tag but is just a string that orders jQuery to create new div with class 'justPad'.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge No, but you can, if it helps you relax. ;-) jQuery does the right thing without it.

Comment: Yes it sure will help me relate... :D... Do I just add that before the `[0]`?

Comment: BTW... Thank you. That actually worked :). Now to close the `DIV` ;)

Comment: No. You would use `$('<div class="justPad"></div>')`. I think you need to take a break and learn jQuery basics. You're moving to fast.