# How to use jQuery .each() function by class name

Tags: jquery

In a loop I have some checkboxs that I set a class name :

```
class="ids[]"
```

Because my loop is inside a form,at first time I want to find out any `checkbox` is check or not.

```
var ids = new Array();

$('.ids[]').each(function(index, element) { 
    if(this.checked) {
        ids.push($(this).val());
    }
});

if(ids.length == 0 ) {
    alert('not checked any checkbox');
    return false;
}
```

---

`$('.ids[]').each...` not fetch anything.

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the jQuery each() function to loop through classname elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292037/using-the-jquery-each-function-to-loop-through-classname-elements)

Comment: The `[]` are most probably treated by jQuery as attribute selector syntax. Use `.ids\\[\\]` instead, although such class names look very odd.

Comment: why would you ever need (or use) `[]` in a className?

Comment: you need the square brackets for `name="ids[]"` atrribute, not for the classname